# Extract data from PDF to Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA for copying PDF data to an Excel sheet, using Word to convert that data:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()  '(load pdf)
    Dim o As Variant
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    o = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe C:\Users\User Profile Name\Desktop\Book1.pdf2", vbNormalFocus)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
    SendKeys ("^a")
    SendKeys ("^c")
    SendKeys "%{F4}"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    appWord.Visible = False
    appWord.Documents.Add.Content.Paste
    With appWord
        .Selection.WholeStory
        .Selection.Copy
        .ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        .Quit
    End With

    MsgBox " pdf is loaded "
    MsgBox " Paste to EXCEL "

    Set wkSheet = ActiveSheet
    wkSheet.Range("A1").Select
    wkSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

As we can see, this will fetch the PDF from "C:\Users\User Profile Name\Desktop\Book1.pdf2".

I need the help to have it changed to open the "choose file" box, so that I can choose the PDF that I want converted?

Comment: Excuse, I would also like if it could ask me to "select a Sheet" to which I want the results pasted.

Comment: Search for `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)`. Plenty of examples on how to implement it here on SO. msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel

Comment: or Application.GetOpenFileName in newer versions. For choosing sheet name, look at InputBox()

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding may be below code helps you.

```
'    
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()  '(load pdf)
Dim useSel As Integer
Dim file As String
Dim o As Variant



'allow to select only one file
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
'Remove all filters
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear
'Add a custom filter to select pdf file only
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Add("PDF Files Only", "*.pdf")
'make the file dialog visible to the user
useSel = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
'user choice
If useSel <> 0 Then

file = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

'if choice is false then close sub
Else
Exit Sub
End If


'your code
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

 o = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe " + file, vbNormalFocus)
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
   SendKeys ("^a")
SendKeys ("^c")
 SendKeys "%{F4}"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
 Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 appWord.Visible = False
 appWord.Documents.Add.Content.Paste
With appWord

       .Selection.WholeStory
       .Selection.Copy
       .ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
       .Quit
End With

MsgBox " pdf is loaded "
MsgBox " Paste to EXCEL "


   Set wkSheet = ActiveSheet
    wkSheet.Range("A1").Select
    wkSheet.Paste

End Sub
```